# problems with postasync HttpContent

Tags: c#, http, model-view-controller, asp.net-web-api

im using PostAsync to call my external webAPI programatically in my back end.

I have had the method working using a httpget, however turning it into a post seems more problematic, due to the httpcontent object required. when awaiting, the status code is always a 404 due to the data not being passed over.

```
 using (var client = new HttpClient())
        {
            client.BaseAddress = new Uri("http://localhost:52715/");
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(
                new System.Net.Http.Headers.MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
            var data = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(new { user = "JOHNSMITH" });
            HttpResponseMessage response = await client.PostAsync("MessageUser",  new StringContent(data, Encoding.UTF8, "text/json"));
            if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("\n sent signal to dept");
            }
        }
```

Comment: Please, so the code for the post action in your controller, and the route configuration for your API.

Comment: everything in the API wires up fine. - like i said, it works with a httpget, but not a httppost, despite the action being marked with both attributes